# resque-status and resque-scheduler for recurring jobs

Tags: ruby, resque

I have the following configuration for my resque system (no rails just Sinatra base) where I have bunch of recurring jobs scheduled from a yml file

```
resque (1.23.0)
resque-scheduler (2.0.0)
resque-status (0.4.0)
```

The recurring schedule appears on the 'Schedule' tab and when I click on a 'Queue Now' button the status also appears on the 'Statuses' tab, the problem is that when the recurring jobs automatically run, they don't appear on the 'Statuses' tab.. my resque_schedule.yml looks something like this

```
email_notifier:
  every: 5m
  custom_job_class: Process_Notification_Emails
  queue: email_notifier
  args: 
  description: "Process mail notifications"
```

Note: These scheduled jobs are actually running every 5 minutes and are behaving as expected,the only issue I'm having is that they don't appear on the 'Statuses' tab unless I manually enqueue them

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Support for resque-status (and other custom jobs)**
>
> Some Resque extensions like resque-status use custom job classes with
>   a slightly different API signature. Resque-scheduler isn't trying to
>   support all existing and future custom job classes, instead it
>   supports a schedule flag so you can extend your custom class and make
>   it support scheduled job.
>
> Let's pretend we have a JobWithStatus class called FakeLeaderboard

```
class FakeLeaderboard < Resque::JobWithStatus
  def perform
    # do something and keep track of the status
  end
end
```

> And then a schedule:

```
create_fake_leaderboards:
  cron: "30 6 * * 1"
  queue: scoring
  custom_job_class: FakeLeaderboard
  args:
  rails_env: demo
  description: "This job will auto-create leaderboards for our online demo and the status will update as the worker makes progress"
```

> If your extension doesn't support scheduled job, you would need to
>   extend the custom job class to support the #scheduled method:

```
module Resque
  class JobWithStatus
    # Wrapper API to forward a Resque::Job creation API call into
    # a JobWithStatus call.
    def self.scheduled(queue, klass, *args)
      create(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler#support-for-resque-status-and-other-custom-jobs

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I already use the latest version of resque-status (directly from git master) that has support for resque-scheduler which does implement the scheduled method... Please take a look at this https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/blob/master/lib/resque/plugins/status.rb

Comment: Are you calling `scheduled` method?  Something like `WorkingJob.scheduled(:queue_name, WorkingJob, @job_args)`?